# hadoop fs command is not working in my system

Tags: hadoop

I installed a single cluster node on my personal laptop. It has successfully installed and jps is displaying all 5 demons, but when I try to enter into on top of hdfs by using `hadoop fs` command it shows "command not found".

Can anyone explain what is the problem and what we have to do to run hdfs commands?

Answer (score 0):

go to the hadoop installation directory

and type

```
bin/hadoop fs -ls /
```

it will return with the directories and files available on the HDFS

Answer (score 0):

I hope the standard blog that you have followed had hadoop installed here:
/usr/local/hadoop/bin

```
ls -l /usr/local/hadoop/bin
root@ashu-700-430qe:/usr/local/hadoop/bin# ls -lrt
total 440
-rwxr-xr-x 1 hduser hadoop   1776 Dec 17 18:52 rcc
-rwxr-xr-x 1 hduser hadoop   7072 Dec 17 18:52 hdfs.cmd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 hduser hadoop  11142 Dec 17 18:52 hdfs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 hduser hadoop   8298 Dec 17 18:52 hadoop.cmd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 hduser hadoop   5479 Dec 17 18:52 hadoop
-rwxr-xr-x 1 hduser hadoop  10895 Dec 17 18:52 yarn.cmd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 hduser hadoop  11380 Dec 17 18:52 yarn
-rwxr-xr-x 1 hduser hadoop 201707 Dec 17 18:52 test-container-executor
-rwxr-xr-x 1 hduser hadoop   5949 Dec 17 18:52 mapred.cmd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 hduser hadoop   5205 Dec 17 18:52 mapred
-rwxr-xr-x 1 hduser hadoop 159223 Dec 17 18:52 container-executor
```

If that is not the case find out where it is installed.
Once you have find it.

```
Then sudo vi /etc/environment 
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/opt/gradle/bin:/usr/local/hadoop/bin"
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
export JAVA_HOME
GRADLE_HOME=/opt/gradle-2.10
export GRADLE_HOME
```

Then just add the hadoop-folder-till-bin-directory into this file.

```
then source /etc/environment
echo $PATH
```

this command should give you the path of hadoop bin directory also.
Now you can run your regular hadoop fs commands now.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

The following command may be needed:

```
sudo su hduser
```

then

```
hadoop fs -ls /
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to askubuntu! 1.) Please use block formatting for commands and verbatim output by either indenting or enclosing in back-ticks. 2.) I see your answer is very similar to the already existing one, but not identical, because of the `sudo su` part. I think it would be helpful to add, why switching to `hduser` may be necessary.